# mailto with dynamic generated pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are working on Asp.net web application. As per requirement, We want to programmatically generate a pdf and need to send the generated pdf using “mailto:”(default email client)  feature as attachment.   Is it possible to send a generated email using “mailto” feature?.

We are stuck with this issue. Any help would be appreciable.

Best Regards,

Ranish

Comment: What possible solution did you explore already? Surely finding _possible_ library methods is what you did first?

Answer (score 0):

You can first save the generated pdf into a temp folder so that you can include this path into the attachment property.

```
<a href='mailto:name@example.com?Subject=SubjectText&Body=BodyText&Attachment="\\Path_to_the_temp_file" '>
```

A more better way would be to create a method that handles the sending of the mail.

Then you can use the `MailMessage` and the `Attachment` objects.

[Namespace System.Net.Mail.Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. As per requirement  we cannot use "MailMessage " option, Since we need to open the  email client to the user. So that user can compose/Edit the content.